# area between curve and straight line

Tags: calculus

Calculate the are enclosed by ${y = 4}$ and ${y = 12 - 2x - x^2}$

My first step is to let equation equal the ohter

${4 = 12 - 2x - x^2}$

This factorises into ${x + 4)(x -2}$

I then use these for the domain:

${\int_{-2}^{4} (16 -2x - x^2) - (- 4) dx}$

Taking the integral

${[16x - x^2 - {x^3\over 3}]}$ and plugging the domain in:

${(64 - 16 - {16\over 3}) - (-32 -4 - {-8\over 3})}$

Am I right so far or have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, you are mistaken in finding intersection points & integration.

plot the graph of downward parabola: $y=12-2x-x^2$ or  $(x+2)^2=-(y-16)$ & the given line: $y=4$ intersecting each other at the points $(-4, 4)$ & $(2, 4)$. Indicate the area required which is given as  $$\int (y_1-y_2)\ dx$$
setting $y_1=12-2x-x^2$ & $y_2=4$ with proper limits $$=\int_{-4}^{2}(12-2x-x^2-4)\ dx $$ 
$$=\left(8x-x^2-\frac{x^3}{3}\right)_{-4}^{2}$$ 
$$=\color{red}{36}$$

Comment: could you please explain how you got the coordinates (-4, 4) and (2, 4) please, it is still unclear where these came from

Comment: Alright, for finding intersection points of the parabola & the line, simply substitute  $y=4$ in the equation $y=12-2x-x^2$ $$4=12-2x-x^2\implies x^2+2x-8=0\ or\ \ (x+4)(x-2)=0\iff x=2, -4$$ hence the intersection points are $(-4, 4)$  & $(2, 4)$

Comment: so you are plugging each x value into the combined equation?

Comment: Notice, you have calculated the values of abscissa $x=2, -4$ & the corresponding values of ordinate are $y=4, 4$  so the points of intersection are $(-4, 4)$ & $(2, 4)$